# Из таблице продуктов, проверить имеется ли продук в закладках у пользователя

Tags: sql, postgresql

У меня есть табилце пользователей:

```
 user_id |  user_name  | ... |
------------------------------
   1     |    name 1   | ... |
   2     |    name 2   | ... |
   3     |    name 3   | ... |
```

В ней храниться вся информация о рользователях.

Есть таблица продуктов:

```
 product_id |  name  | ... |
----------------------------
      1     | name 1 | ... |
      2     | name 2 | ... |
      3     | name 3 | ... |
```

В ней храниться информация о продуктах.

Есть таблица закладок:

```
 bookmark_id |  product_id  | user_id |
---------------------------------------
       1     |       1     |     1    |
       2     |       1     |     2    |
       3     |       3     |     1    |
```

В ней храниться ид продукта и ид пользователя у которого этот продук в закладках. Таблица связана вторичными ключами, то есть из таблицы закладок, поле `product_id` связанно с таблицей `products` и так же поле `user_id` связанно c `users`.

Мне надо вывести результат:

```
 product_id |  product_name  | ... | BOOKMARKS |
------------------------------------------------
      1     | product name 1 | ... |   false   |
      2     | product name 2 | ... |   true    |
      3     | product name 3 | ... |   false   |
```

То есть, по мимо все информации о продукте, надо вывети столбец `BOOKMARKS`, в котором храниться `true` если у пользователя есть продект в закладках и `false` если нет. Но с условием того что для каждого пользваотеля резный.

То есть если у пользователя с ид 1 в закладках первый продукт а второй и третий нет, результат будет такой:

```
 product_id |  product_name  | ... | BOOKMARKS |
------------------------------------------------
      1     | product name 1 | ... |   true    |
      2     | product name 2 | ... |   false   |
      3     | product name 3 | ... |   false   |
```

У пользователя с ид 2 в закладках третий и второй продукт, а первый нет, результат будет такой:

```
 product_id |  product_name  | ... | BOOKMARKS |
------------------------------------------------
      1     | product name 1 | ... |   false   |
      2     | product name 2 | ... |   true    |
      3     | product name 3 | ... |   true    |
```

У пользователя с ид 3 в закладках нет ни одного продукта, результат будет такой:

```
 product_id |  product_name  | ... | BOOKMARKS |
------------------------------------------------
      1     | product name 1 | ... |   false   |
      2     | product name 2 | ... |   false   |
      3     | product name 3 | ... |   false   |
```

Помогите, пожалуйста мне с моей проблемой

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
select p.*, 
       b.product_id is not null BOOKMARKS 
-- или case when b.product_id is null then 'false' else 'true' end 
from products p
left join bookmarks b on p.product_id = b.product_id 
                     and b.user_id = @user_id
```

Comment: Это то что нужно мне, спасибо